# How can I modify date format in Excel VBA, userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a UserForm that automatically populates with given data from a table, I cannot get the format of the date to change. I am not sure where my code went wrong.

```
Set name_ = Display.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test" & labelCounter, True)
    With name_
        .Caption = Format(debt_name_cell, mmm - yy)
        .Left = 10
        .Width = 50
        .Top = 10 * labelCounter
    End With
    Set debt_name_cell = debt_name_cell.Offset(1, 0)
```

[image: The result is always:]

Answer (score 3):

Having a look at the [Microsoft VBA Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692818.aspx) is always a good idea:
[Format Function (Visual Basic for Applications)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx).

There we can see that the second parameter of the `Format` function has to be a string like

```
Format(debt_name_cell, "mmm - yy")
```

---

If you follow VBA Best Practices use `Option Explicit` at the top of every VBA module you would have recognized an issues like that in a second!

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting an answer rewards the contributor for their time and helps others to find a workling solution.